# How to add Oracle constraint to below tables

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

I have three tables:

A {op_id, op_name, .}

B {b_id, op_id, supplier_id, .}

C {c_id, op_id, op_id2, supplier_id, relation, .}

Table B and C have op_id which is foreign key from table A.  In table A op_id is primary key, in table B b_id is primary key and in table C c_id is primary key. In table B supplier_id and op_id may have duplicate records. Now I want to add constraint so that if I delete records from Table B for op_id and if a relationship record exists for op_id in table C then it should not allow me to delete. Is it possible through constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Add the constraints normally as specified by you like below

Table A op_id is primary key, 
in table B b_id is primary key 
and in table C c_id is primary key

Table B and C have op_id which is foreign key from table A

For the last condition that you have specified write a trigger `before delete` on table B and check if the op_id is present in the table C or not - if yes throw an error else allow it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. Can we achieve this with referential integrity constraint ?

Comment: Just tell me one thing - whether if a op_id is inserted into table B then will it be inserted into table C for sure

Comment: No B and C tables are independent, however the table C maintains the relationship details of the op_id + supplier_id.

Comment: Then there is no other way and the only way you could achieve is through trigger as I specified and more over one other way would be writing a trigger `before insert` checking whether the combination of opid + supplier_id is allowed or not

Answer (score 0):

Most of your key constraints are fairly trivial, the difficult bit is the last part, ensuring that you cannot remove rows from B without first removing them from C.

One approach that might work here would be to create a fast-refreshable "on commit" materialised view which returns a count of the number of unique OP_IDs that exist in C but that are not in B. You could then add a check constraint to the view which enforces that the count must always be zero. This constraint would be enforced at the point of commit and would prevent you deleting from B without first deleting from C (deleting from B whilst matching records exist in C would violate the check constraint as the count in the materialized view would be greater than 0). A side effect of this would be that you wouldn't be able to insert into C without first inserting into B.